# вывод inputStream в качестве ответа от сервера

Tags: java

Есть *Java* прослойка между сервером и *Frontend* и все *Ajax* запросы идут через нее. Появилась мысль попробовать ускорить обработку сообщения на *Java* путем считывания `InputStream` по блокам `4096` байт и передачи их в качестве ответа на *Ajax* запрос.

Код написал такой:

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection myCnn = null;
url = new URL("адрес запроса на сервер");
myCnn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

InputStream myResponseStream = myCnn.getInputStream();

try {

 final byte[] myByteBuffer = new byte[4096];
 int myBytesCnt;
 while((myBytesCnt = myResponseStream.read(myByteBuffer)) != -1) {
  response.write(new String(myByteBuffer, "UTF-8"));
 }
} catch (IOException ex) {
 myResponse.setHeader("ErrorCode", "500");
 myResponse.setHeader("ErrorMessage", "Server error. IOException.");
}
```

с таким кодом собственно приходят только `4096` байт, которые вроде как перезаписываются друг на друга, так как где-то посередине, прилетают последние данные.

Тогда я решил цикл переписать так:

```
String myResponceString = "";
while((myBytesCnt = myResponseStream.read(myByteBuffer)) != -1) {
 myResponceString = myResponceString + new String(myByteBuffer, "UTF-8");
}
response.write(myResponceString);
```

ну по началу я использовал `stringBuffer`, но работает также. А именно: ответ приходит целый, последовательный, но через каждые видимо `4096` байт, вижу знаки `??` и вот от них уже избавиться никак не получается, как бы я не пытался.

Собственно вопросы:

- могу я как-то передавать, только что полученный от сервера, кусок данных, сразу в качестве ответа *Ajax* запросу так, чтобы поток передачи не прерывался и аккуратно данные дописывались бы до достижения конца ответа.
- в чем может быть проблема со знаками вопроса? Я вроде и кодировку указываю сразу, и в строку конкатенировал, но ничего не помогает.

Comment: что вы за данные там передавать пытаетесь?

Comment: `response` - что за объект?

Comment: передаю ajax запрос, получаю данные в JSON. response это объект IPortalComponentResponse sap портала который возвращает мне ответ с данными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде 2 проблемы:

1. Вы игнорируете значение, возвращаемое методом `read`. Точнее, вы сравниваете его с `-1`, но больше никак не используете. При успехе [`InputStream.read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) возвращает количество байтов, считанных в массив, и оно может быть меньше длины массива, поэтому далее нужно использовать только ту часть массива, которая была успешно заполнена.
2. Вы неправильно перекодируете строки. Во-первых, а нужно ли перекодировать? Если нет, можно сразу писать полученные байты в ответ:

   ```
   OutputStream outputStream = ...;

   outputStream.write(myByteBuffer, 0, myBytesCnt);
   ```

   Если же перекодировать нужно, то нужно это делать не кусками, как у вас сейчас, а потоком, чтобы избежать разрывов многобайтовых символов на границах буфера. Как-то так:

   ```
   // InputStreamReader займётся преобразованием потока байтов в символы
   InputStreamReader myResponseStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(myCnn.getInputStream(), кодировка_ответа_стороннего_сервера);

   Writer writer = ...;

   try {
     final char[] myCharBuffer = new char[4096];
     int myCharsCnt;
     while((myCharsCnt = myResponseStreamReader.read(myCharBuffer)) != -1) {
       writer.write(myCharBuffer, 0, myCharsCnt);
     }
   } catch (...) {
     ...
   }
   ```

И это всё наверняка можно более элегантно переписать в Java 8.